# Hilbert Spaces-Linear Algebra

Tags: reference-request

I'm taking a course of linear algebra and as one of the themes this:

- Hilbert spaces: Hilbert bases, Fourier expansions, dimension of Hilbert, Riesz theorem.

I have some text on Hilbert spaces but are more concerned with the analysis of linear algebra. Any suggestions for reading?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try picking up a book on functional analysis or fourier theory.  If you like Riesz, you might like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486662896) for functional analysis.  (Cheap too!)

Comment: Thanks! Cheap is importand :)